# running a time interval computation in the background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimeinterval

I have a NSTimeInterval which is basically

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate: [NSDate date]];
```

I want this computation to be always running in the background when I am in a view X, so I can display a timer counting down in a UILabel.. how do I do this? It's like in the groupon iphone app, but it doesn't show it in details of seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) to get a method called at a set time interval (however this is all performed on the main thread, not on a background thread):

```
- (void)setupTimer {
    //Start a timer to call update updateInterval: every 1 second
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                               target:self
                                               selector:@selector(updateInterval:)
                                             userInfo:nil
                                              repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateInterval:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSTimeInterval interval = [date1 timeIntervaleSinceDate:[NSDate date]];
    //Do other things like updating the label
}
```

Comment: Correct, the repeat interval can also be less than 1.

Comment: that scheduledTimerWithTimerInterval is not listed http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

Comment: That was a typo, I've fixed it in the answer.  It is scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:, here is a link to the method in the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:

Comment: instead of action, it should be selector

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I need to be more attentive when typing out these long method calls.

Comment: You could make it run on a background thread by calling setupTimer from a background thread, but then you would need to set up a run loop, and you still have to call the main thread to update the display, so that really wouldn't be beneficial in this case.